# Get a new array from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, loops

I want to create a new array with the 'itemDetails' from the following array. In this array inside every 'poDetails', 'itemDetails' is listed, I need to create a new array with all these 'itemDetails'(if it is repeated also). I tried some methods using map, foreach, but whiling pushing to new array its not getting as expected

```
expecting result = 
[ {"cic": 36200097,"description": "TEST ITEM","qty": 312},
  {"cic": 36200038,"description": "TEST ITEM","qty": 156},
  {"cic": 36200097,"description": "TEST ITEM","qty": 468},
  {"cic": 36200038,"description": "TEST ITEM","qty": 156},
  {"cic": 36200097,"description": "TEST ITEM","qty": 468}]

   obj= {
      "toolName": "WHSE Case",
      "poDetails": [
        {
          "po": 678676,
          "itemDetails": [
            {
              "cic": 36200097,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 312,
            },
            {
              "cic": 36200038,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 156,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "po": 680510,
          "itemDetails": [
            {
              "cic": 36200097,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 468,
            },
            {
              "cic": 36200038,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 156,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "po": 682110,
          "itemDetails": [
            {
              "cic": 36200097,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 468,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }

this.gridRows = array.poDetails;
 this.gridRows.forEach(row => {
      if (row.itemDetails) {
        this.formatedData.push(row.itemDetails);
      }
    });
```

this is waht I tried and not getting the result as expected.

Comment: `[].concat(...array.poDetails.map(p => p.itemDetails))`

Comment: Don't post code in comments, [edit] the post and include the code there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you tried already, you clearly didn't try hard enough. A simple map + flat is all it takes.

```js
const data = {
  toolName: 'WHSE Case',
  poDetails: [
    {
      po: 678676,
      itemDetails: [
        { cic: 36200097, description: 'TEST ITEM', qty: 312, },
        { cic: 36200038, description: 'TEST ITEM', qty: 156, },
      ],
    },
    {
      po: 680510,
      itemDetails: [
        { cic: 36200097, description: 'TEST ITEM', qty: 468, },
        { cic: 36200038, description: 'TEST ITEM', qty: 156, },
      ],
    },
    {
      po: 682110,
      itemDetails: [
        { cic: 36200097, description: 'TEST ITEM', qty: 468, },
      ],
    },
  ],
};


const grouped = data.poDetails.map(({ itemDetails }) => itemDetails).flat(1);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: No, you'd need to flatten the `itemDetails` since that's an array itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const myarr =  array.poDetails.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 const {itemDetails} = cur;
 if (itemDetails?.length) {
   acc = acc.concat(itemDetails)
 }
 return acc;
}, []);
```

Also, I'd adise renaming 'array' to something like an objectname, because it is not an array. It is an object.

Answer (score 0):

map returns an array with exact length it is used, so it can't be used in this case.
You need to initialize your result array, and push all items to it.

```js
   array= {
      "toolName": "WHSE Case",
      "poDetails": [
        {
          "po": 678676,
          "itemDetails": [
            {
              "cic": 36200097,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 312,
            },
            {
              "cic": 36200038,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 156,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "po": 680510,
          "itemDetails": [
            {
              "cic": 36200097,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 468,
            },
            {
              "cic": 36200038,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 156,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "po": 682110,
          "itemDetails": [
            {
              "cic": 36200097,
              "description": "TEST ITEM",
              "qty": 468,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
    let result = [];
    array.poDetails.forEach(poDetail => result.push(...poDetail.itemDetails));
    console.log(result);
```